# AJAX call display response from php script in html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a html file where users can input a value.
I wrote a script in PHP that checks if this value is present in the databse. If it's present it returns

> {"active":true}

Now my goals is that when the user inputs their value and submit they will be redirected to a certain page if this active is true. If it's false they should see an error message.

So here's what I've tried with my AJAX call:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
 $(".checkform").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "api/check.php", 
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        if(data.active=="true"){
            alert("success");
            location.href="where_you_want";
         }else{
             alert("failure");
         }
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<form action="api/check.php" id="requestacallform" method="GET" name="requestacallform" class="formcheck">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="input-group">                               
                    <input id="#" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Jouw subdomein" name="name"/>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Aanmelden" class="btn btn-blue" />
</form>
```

For some reason I get an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

I am new to AJAX and I am not sure if what I am trying is correct.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your HTML code?

Comment: where do you get redirected too, I guess the page reloads right?

Comment: Share your html code also

Comment: @ArunGhosh I updated OP

Comment: @Velimir I get redirected to /api/check.php my script

Comment: @FrankLucas: not able to find class **`.aanmeldenmodal`** in your HTML

Comment: @ArunGhosh I added the class to my form but nothing changes when I submit

Comment: I get redirected to localhost:8888/api/check.php?name=bla and it displays the output of my check.php

Answer (score 0):

I am updating my answer in whole

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="api/check.php" id="requestacallform" method="GET" name="requestacallform" class="formcheck">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">                               
                <input id="txt1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Jouw subdomein" name="name"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Aanmelden" class="btn btn-blue checkform" />
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

jQuery part is like

```
  $("document").ready(function () {

    $("body").on("click", ".checkform", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var request = $("#txt1").value;
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: {request: 'request'},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
           if(data.active==true){
               alert("success");
           }else{
                alert("failure");
           }

        }
    });

    });
});
```

ajax.php should be like this

```
if(isset($_GET['request'])){
  //check for the text
   echo json_encode($arr);     
}
```

Comment: `data.active` is a boolean, not a string.

Comment: Can you checkout updated OP with your answer pls I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined`

Comment: one minute i am checking

Comment: @SanoojT I don't understand how I can access the json_encode($data); response from my php script so weird

Comment: @FrankLucas its almost finished i will update my answer

Comment: @SanoojT I am waiting patiently :)

Comment: @FrankLucas check the answer

Comment: @SanoojT thanks for your answer but unfortunately it doesn't work. When I submit my form nothing happens, no reload no error message and nothing in console I have no idea what is going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
  $(".aanmeldenmodal").submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

In api/check.php
You can pass data in json format

```
$json = json_encode($data);
retrun $json;
```

You can also not share any data so You can remove data from jQuery.

```
data:data
```

Your Jquery look like this:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
 $(".checkform").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "api/check.php", 
  success: function(data) {
    if(data.active=="true"){
        alert("success");
        location.href="where_you_want";
     }else{
         alert("failure");
     }
  }
});
return false;
});
});
```